# How to get the document auto id of firebase in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to get the auto assigned id of document:
[id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxK3L.png)

Comment: It's not very clear what problem you've encountered when getting this ID. Did you [get the documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) yet, or [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to get that specific document? If you edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show what you've already tried based on that documentation and the many tutorials out there, it's much more likely that someone here can help.

Answer (score 0):

I dont realy understand your problem.
Can you share with us the part of your code?!
So we can help you.